# Deducting charitable donations under new U.S. tax law

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, charitable-contributions

I usually donate about $20k to charities every year, and I don't have many other deductions to claim. Given that the new tax law doubles the standard deduction to $24k, I effectively don't get tax benefits from my charitable donations anymore because I don't have enough deductions to itemize.

Are there any creative loopholes to get around this so that when I donate to charity I reduce my taxable income?  I know that one quasi-solution is to save up my charitable donations for several years and then give away a bunch of money within the same tax year so that I surpass the standard deduction in that year. But that's not good for the charities.

Are there any other ways to get a tax benefit from charitable donations under the new law?  I own a small business, in case that provides any opportunities (though I gather that I can't write off cash donations made in the name of the business).

Comment: You may not get the deduction per se, but the standard deduction is much larger, so you *are* getting the tax advantage, plus some $4K more.

Comment: @Norm: No, it means that people with significant deductions lose out on what used to be the individual exemption (Adding it into the standard deduction made it unavailable to those who itemize), causing AGI to be higher than it used to be.  It pretty much cancels out the savings from the percentage rate reductions.

Comment: @taxypayer22847 Having your business do the charitable contribution seems to be the way to go. At least in the case of a C-corp, the company would make the $20 donation, and reduce your W-2 by that amount. But maybe this isn't possible if your business is considered a pass-through? Is this what you're alluding to in your question?

Comment: @taxypayer22847: Even before the new tax law, the mortgage deduction didn't get you anywhere near the standard deduction unless you've got either a really expensive home or a really bad loan.

Comment: @R.. I don't know what you consider "a really expensive home," but between interest and property taxes on our definitely-not-a-mansion, and sales tax (in lieu of state income tax), my household in a coastal state was a few thousand above the former standard deduction. Then I got to deduct charitable contributions. Then I got to add personal exemptions. Under the new tax law, my household's taxable income definitely went up. (Whether our taxes went up or down overall, remains to be seen.)

Comment: If your business is a sole proprietorship, you can't take charitable contributions as a business expense. If it's a corporation or LLC, I don't know what the rules are.

Comment: @stannius: Median is 200k so let's say 300k (obviously that's not going to fly if you want to live in SF or something). Interest at 3.5%, 15yr is under 6k a year.

Comment: @R.. Some of us are single. Standard deduction for single was $6,350 in 2017 tax year. I live in a rather cheap area and have a good loan and mortgage interest + sales tax + property tax was in excess of standard deduction for single filers for the first few years of the 15-year loan.

Comment: @R.. that's the average interest, but as I'm sure you know the interest is higher in the earlier years and lower in the later years.

Comment: And, I couldn't find any statistics (just "which should I choose?" articles) but I'm pretty sure 30 year loans are far more common (I guess people like "really bad loans")

Comment: @stannius: Yes. If you're single, for several years the mortgage interest deduction probably helped you even if you don't have other large deductions to get past the standard deduction. Now that possibility is pretty much gone. I do consider 30yr loans "really bad loans". With the difference in interest rates and total interest to be paid, the monthly payment is fairly similar between 15yr and 30yr loans, and if you can't afford the difference you're almost surely better off just buying a less expensive house.

Comment: @R. there's zero point quoting us US medians or averages, spread across people who bought homes 20+ years ago and/or in cheaper areas. Consider the deductions of a recent home purchaser in any of the top ten US metros. Different thing. Hence these sort of questions. From FY 2018 it will only get worse. This is a real thing for some of us. Telling us "but it's cheaper in Milwaukee/Detroit/..." is unhelpful.

Answer (score 48):

I’m in the same boat as you. Charitable contributions make up the majority of my itemized deductions, and I probably won’t be itemizing next year. Here is how I look at it:

If I end up taking the standard deduction, instead of deducting my charitable contributions, I get to deduct *more* than my charitable contributions. That’s a better deal for me than if the standard deduction had stayed below my level of giving.

Even before the new tax reform laws, I don’t give to charity *solely* for the purpose of getting a tax deduction. (Giving $1 only so that I can get $0.25 back is not rational.) I give for other reasons, and those reasons haven’t changed with the new laws.

Comment: @BenMiller Sure, but that doesn't change the way for those who donate <24K (I guess 14K for those with 10K SALT deduction), giving is more expensive than it used to be.

Comment: The new standard deduction is not a better deal than the old combination of standard deduction and personal exemption.

Comment: @BenVoigt For some, that might be true, but don’t forget that the tax rates dropped in each bracket as well.

Comment: Yes, overall it isn't any worse (and for people who were already using the standard deduction, it's obviously quite a bit better)

Comment: @BenMiller the only thing I would add to your excellent answer is that you are now free to give to anyone and record keeping is simplified.  For example, that mom of young children who has breast cancer.  You can give directly to her with impunity as the tax deductions are off the table anyway.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, and ignores macroeconomics of lower taxes. Deficit spending affects everyone, but this tax break will benefit other people more than it benefits the OP. So it's far from clear that the OP is better off.

Comment: It may not feel the same as before, OP was likely getting a large refund at tax time and now the amount will trickle in throughout the year.  You may also want to try taking the difference in your paycheck before and after the tax cut and routing that difference into a separate account that you cash at the end of the year.

Answer (score 24):

Probably the best approach which can work very well depending on your cashflow and the giving in question (whether it's time sensitive or not):

- 2018: save all $20k in the bank
- January 1, 2019: give all $20k to charity (from 2018)
- 2019: give another $20k
- Dec31, 2019: (optional) give another 20k
- 2020: give none

This means you will take the standard deduction in 2018/2020 and itemize $60k in 2019.

You can sometimes put property taxes into this too.

I've saved a ton on taxes using this even before the new tax code with this approach and will likely prioritize it even moreso now that the standard deduction increased so much.

You briefly mentioned this as "save a few years" but there's no reason to save a few years. While you "late load" charitable giving in 2018, you preload all your 2020 so depending on the recipient in question it may be a neutral cash flow option.

If you are particularly worried about cashflow implications for the charity and can afford it you could move the entire thing up a year and just give $40k this year (the 2019 giving at end of year 2018) which will mean the charities see the money at the same pace. Depending on scale of the recipient you may want to give them a heads up (ie if you donate 20k to a charity with a 100k budget) that your end of year 2018/2019 donation is intended to be your 2019/2020 donation.

Comment: The question already covered this; the saving in earlier years is what makes the lump sum giving possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt OP rejected it with a false premise though.

Comment: This is certainly a reasonable strategy, although the OP’s point that this is not as good for the charity is valid.

Comment: @BenMiller I specifically mention ways to mitigate that problem.

Comment: @ElysianFields Understood. If you’ve already got a lump sum sitting around and want to give early, the charity obviously benefits. But they will have to wait years for the next donation. I’m sure they’ll be happy to get a donation any way you want to give it. +1

Comment: @BenMiller and realistically if a charity has a budget of $10M/year whether you give 20k in two years or 40k/0k really won't matter much at all (assuming the entirety of 20k went to one year).

Comment: @ElysianFields Indeed, but some of us give to smaller charities with smaller budgets for which our gifts are a significant part of their continued existence.

Comment: @BenMiller I also specifically address _that_ situation and ways to mitigate it, too, in my answer...

Answer (score 15):

A [donor advised charity fund](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donor-advised_fund) can allow you to set aside several years worth of charity and then give donations whenever you wish.

For example you can put 40-60k in the fund during a single tax year and write it off then. As the next few years progress, you can donate the money whenever you wish.

Comment: One year, I owned stock that had a large long term cap gain. I used this strategy to avoid the 15% tax as well as group my donations in a high tax year, effectively giving me a 50% tax refund on the donation that year. And I distributed to charities over the following years.

Comment: When you put money in a donor advised fund, you deduct your contributions in the year that you put the money in the fund. This isn’t really any different than if you give the money directly to the charity. The fund is only useful if you don’t yet know who you want to give the money to.

Comment: The benefit is that the charity never sees a change in the giving pattern, yet you can make a deduction of 5 years worth of contributions every 5 years.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Not really. They only see no change if you’ve already got 5 years worth of giving saved up in advance. And if you do, the charity would rather get that money up front than have to wait for it to be doled out over the next 5 years. And you get no tax benefit to putting the lump sum in the fund vs. just giving the sum to the charity directly.

Comment: @BenMiller Presumably, you can buy stocks with the money in the fund, so the charity isn't losing out from a time-discount point of view.

Comment: @Accumulation isn't the whole point of a charity to *do something* though? I'm sure they'd rather have $$ now so they can work harder on their mission immediately, rather than wait however many years to get $$$ instead.

Comment: @CactusCake et al - this is a reasonable solution if you have significantly more money than your normal donations, and budget a certain amount for donations per year.  Give five years' worth up front to the fund, minus a bit for assumed growth, taking some of your regular investment capital out of circulation for a few years.  If you plan it right and guess the growth correctly, you can actually end up revenue neutral on all sides.

Answer (score 0):

Giving varying amounts to the charity probably isn't a problem for them, unless they're small. But if you want to avoid that, there are various loopholes with loans. If the charity is willing to play along, you can "loan" them money each year, then forgive several years of loans at once. You can then claim the amount of the loan as a charitable donation for that year. You might be able to set up a foundation, "loan" money to the foundation, have the foundation then give the money to charity, and then forgive the loans. But you should probably check with a tax expert to see if the IRS would call shenanigans on that.